# How can I find the maximum and minimum prices for each product in specific shops using Sequelize in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a SQL database with the following relationships:

- `Shop` has many-to-many relationship with `Product` via `shop_has_product`.
- `shop_has_product` has a one-to-many relationship with `price_read`.

I'm trying to find the maximum and minimum prices for each product in each specific shop. My current code snippet fetches prices across all shops instead of just one.

```js
const products = await models.shop.findAll({
  attributes: ['name', 'address'],
  include: [
    {
      model: models.shop_has_product,
      as: 'shop_has_products',
      include: [
        {
          model: models.product,
          as: 'Product',
          where: { id: productId }
        },
        {
          model: models.price_read,
          as: 'price_reads',
          attributes: [
            [sequelize.fn('MAX', sequelize.col('price')), 'maxPrice'],
            [sequelize.fn('MIN', sequelize.col('price')), 'minPrice']
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      model: models.street,
      as: 'Street',
      attributes: ['name'],
      include: [
        {
          model: models.city,
          as: 'City',
          where: { name: city }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

How can I modify this query to find max and min prices for each product in specific shops?

There's code for needed models:
product - id, name, code, Brand_id, Subcategory_id
shop - id, name, x_location, y_location, status, address, Street_id
shop_has_product - id, Shop_id, Product_id
price_read - id, price, date_from, date_to, confirm_number, reject_number, Shop_has_Product_id, Currency_id.

Comment: It would also be helpful to the question if you gave an example object/array for users to view

Comment: You mean models from sequelize?

Comment: Yes ..  I we knew what the structure from `models` looked like it will be easier to determine the source of your problem within your current code set

Comment: I've added the attributes of each object

Comment: You just need to use a subquery via Sequelize.literal in `attributes` prop of `shop_has_product` include